# Numpy argsort returns unexpected answer

Tags: python

I have a simple numpy argsort() question.

In the following example, I would expect the result to be
array([2, 0, 1]), since 10 is the smallest number, follow by 20, then 30.   But the actual result is array([1, 2, 0]).

Please help to explain why that is the case?

```
import numpy as np
x = np.array([30, 10, 20])
np.argsort(x)
```

Answer (score 4):

It is the other way around: `argsort` gives you the array of indeces in increasing order of elements: `x[argsort(x)]` is the ordered array.

Comment: In the above example, where the result is array([1, 2, 0]), what is the 2 refering to?